Wordpress Elementor Loop Grid Custom Query Order change
I have an Elementor Archive Template created using a Loop Grid with the Current Query post type activated so that when a post category is clicked, it shows post from that category only.
The issue:
It is currently set to descending order. I need it to be in ascending order.
This is the order it currently shows:
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
This is what I'd like it to show:
Post 3
Post 2
Post 1
Is there any way to achieve this with custom code?
Elementor support - No response. Just stated it isn't possible from their side.
Various articles looked through but none pertaining to the order of DESC to ASC only for filtering custom field data.
Creating custom query ID and hooking ito one of elementors articles but didn't work:
// Showing posts ordered descending
add_action( 'elementor/query/product_post_filter', function( $query ) {
    $query->set('orderby','DESC');
  });

